# Is there have any ways to get the dynamic html by python

Tags: html, webdriver

I want the dynamic html

But driver.page_source can just give me the Source html
I have ever saw a way by Java

```java
WebElement webElement = webDriver.findElement(By.id("ColumnContainer"));
    List<WebElement> listLink = webElement.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for (int i = 0; (i + 2) < 50; i += 2) {
        System.out.println(listLink.get(i).getAttribute("href") + "/"
                + listLink.get(i + 1).getText());
    }
```

Of course，I only use the python so I dont know whether it is useful
And now,I need the right way by python,Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Following is the equivalent python code for what you have given in question

**Please refer following code**

```
webElement = webDriver.find_element_by_id("ColumnContainer");
listLink = webElement.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
i = 0
while (i + 2) < 50 : 
    print(listLink[i].get_attribute("href") + "/" + listLink[i+1].text)
    i += 2
```